# How can I achieve SQL Pivot statement from LINQ

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am looking to achieve below SQL statement from LINQ. I am not sure whether is it possible? Can someone advice me on this?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, (DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, S.SampleDrawn), 0)), 101) [Date], [Range] =
        CASE 
            WHEN ProbBacteremia >= 0 AND ProbBacteremia < 0.50 THEN 'Low'
            WHEN ProbBacteremia >= 0.50 AND ProbBacteremia < 0.75 THEN 'Med' 
            ELSE 'High'
        END
    FROM Result.Calculation C INNER JOIN Data.SampleSet S ON C.SampleSetID = S.ID  WHERE  S.SampleDrawn >= DATEADD(WEEK,-1,GETDATE())) o
    PIVOT
    (
        COUNT(o.[Range])
        FOR [Range] IN (
        [Low], [Med], [High])
    ) pt
    ORDER BY [Date]
```

Result of the above query will be as below

```
Date        Low Med High
09/04/2017  370 174 175
09/11/2017  764 352 389
09/18/2017  759 384 360
09/25/2017  765 385 404
10/02/2017  115 48  56
```

Note that, above date has grouped by week. Ie. 09/04 , 09/11, 09/18 etc. I did lot of research but i found only to group by Week Number.

This is as far as i could come up with LINQ which will return me the below result set.

```
data = (from a in context.Calculations
                             where a.SampleSet.SampleDrawn >= dtStart && (isDeptFilter || a.SampleSet.Department == location)
                             group a by new { Text = RangeProvider(a.ProbBacteremia * 100, riskCats), Date = a.SampleSet.SampleDrawn.Date } into groupedData
                             orderby groupedData.Key.Date ascending
                             select new { Value = groupedData.Count(), Text = groupedData.Key.Text, Date = groupedData.Key.Date.ToShortDateString() }).ToList();

public static string RangeProvider(int value)
        {
            if (value > 0 && value <= 25)
            { return "Low"; }
            if (value > 25 && value <= 75)
            { return "Medium"; }
            if (value > 75 && value <= 90)
            { return "High"; }
            else
            { return "Very High"; }
        }
```

Result dataset of the obver LINQ is

```
Date        Text Value
09/04/2017  Low  65
09/04/2017  Med  80
09/04/2017  High 40
09/05/2017  Low  30
10/05/2017  Med  50
10/05/2017  High 44
```

Hope this explains what I'm trying to achieve. Please can someone help me with this?

Comment: there is not native pivot in linq, but you can create your own https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSEFPivotOperation-cbdd79db

Comment: This is one of those recurring questions that never get a satisfactory answer because there is none.

Comment: OK I understand. Dose anyone know how to group by the above result set by weeks? Using LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Well as a work-around i have used the Entity Framework Core's "*FromSQL*" method to execute my stored procedure which take cares of all the GROUP BY's.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

```
data = (from a in context.Calculations
             where a.SampleSet.SampleDrawn >= dtStart && (isDeptFilter || a.SampleSet.Department == location)
             group a by new { Text = RangeProvider(a.ProbBacteremia * 100, riskCats), Date = a.SampleSet.SampleDrawn.Date } into groupedData
             orderby groupedData.Key.Date ascending
             select new { 
                 Date = groupedData.Key.Date.ToShortDateString() ,
                 Low = ( groupedData.Key.Text =="Low" )?groupedData.Count() : 0,
                 Medium = ( groupedData.Key.Text =="Medium" )?groupedData.Count() : 0,
                 High = ( groupedData.Key.Text =="High" )?groupedData.Count() : 0,
                 VeryHigh = ( groupedData.Key.Text =="Very High" )?groupedData.Count() : 0
             }).ToList();
```